# Proper way of using Models with foriegnkey in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-models

I'm new to Django and I know little bit about databases.

Let me explain my problem.
For example I have two models- Person and Car (A person can have multiple cars.)

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name
    username
    password
    #some more user attributes.

class Car(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    car_name
    car_price
    #other car atrributes
```

Currently I'm working with models like this but somebody told me that you should use like below -

```
class Car(models.Model):
    car_name
    car_price
    #other car atrributes 

class Person(models.Model):
    name
    username
    password
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    #some more user attributes.
```

Noticed reverse relationship? from person to Car or Car to person which one should I use.
I know I can use `related_name` value in ForeignKey field for reverse lookup. I'm just curious about efficiency,standard and other advantages of one over other.

PS: although first one I'm using currently and its working perfectly.

Comment: Your first condition is right - `Person` has multiple `Cars`. Now, in the second usecase, a Peron can have only 1 car as foreignkey. The person who recommended you the change, probably means a `ManyToManyField` - Many `Person` references multiple `Car`

Comment: @karthikr : but I can create one more object of Car model and same person can point to this object as well. I mean a person can point to two car objects, isn't that correct?

Comment: The same person object? - NO

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a car can have only one owner.
Then, I would write it this way:

```
class Car(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='cars")

class Person(models.Model):
  # ... fields unrelated to cars
```